# ggplot2: fill & position='dodge' for geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do you use two variables to create an x-axis? I want to show the value on the y-axis for all possible combinations of two predictors.

For geom_bar, all you need to do is use the fill and position='dodge' aesthetics. This does not seem to work for geom_line. I could manually create an interaction term and restructure my data frame but there must be a way to do this quicker.

This seems like a rather simple question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere!

Thank you.

Edit: Sorry, more information--I want a graph that looks like this:
[image]

This is a representation of what I'd like the graph to look like. I've made up the data and plotted it in Excel. You can see how the x-axis is being shared by two variables, one nested within the other. Both variables are numeric, with two levels each.

I'd prefer to avoid manually creating an interaction term because it seems like the more crude way of doing it. Ggplot is very flexible and I'm guessing what I have in mind would be possible.

Comment: What does *"all possible combinations... of two variables to create an x-axis"* mean? Show a snippet of sample data using `str()` or `dput()`. Are your variables categorical, logical, integer, string, numeric... ? We're not mindreaders you know...

Comment: *"I could manually create an interaction term and restructure my data frame"*... and/or use as.factor(). This may be the best solution, I don't see that it's a big deal, show us your code and tell us what you dislike about it.

Comment: As to "fill & position='dodge' for geom_line", there isn't any... what do you want to achieve? **Post a picture of a similar graph.** [geom_area or geom_ribbon](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/)? A line-graph with discontinuous gaps between series? or what?

Answer (score 0):

Until you post details about your data, the general answer is:

1) for the x-axis, like you already said:

```
interaction(as.factor(df$var1), as.factor(df$var2), drop = TRUE)
```

I don't see what's undesirable about that, it's a one-liner, you can even inline it with the `ggplot()` call. What's the problem?
You might just want to manipulate the order of each individual `factor(levels = ...)`, or reorder the output from interaction?

2) you also seem to be asking about a plot type, or geom. But without any details.
As to "fill & position='dodge' for geom_line", there isn't any... what do you want to achieve? Post a picture of a similar graph. [geom_area or geom_ribbon](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/)? A line-graph with discontinuous gaps between series? or what?